# Plumbing Adjust toilet water level

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, water, toilet

Anyone know how to adjust the toilet water fill level, with this valve?

It has no screw, so I cannot tell.

[image]

Comment: So you did understand what I wrote, I thought my English was good enough. But your comment has gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like the brass bit allows the height of the black float to change.

Adjust up or down to get where you need.

[image]

Comment: I put a follow up question here, thanks https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/257982/water-fill-valve-adjusting-hole